# Font Awesome icons break during any Javascript errors

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Why do Font Awesome icons show up as flashing question marks anytime there is a Javascript error on a page?

The correct Font Awesome icon flashes correctly for 1 second and then changes to ?

You can see some broken icons on this page for reference. Also worth noting this a Shopify site with plugins that may have errors from time to time so it's hard to keep a site like this 100% console error-free. I've had this issues with both Font Awesome 4 and Font Awesome 5:

https://outdoor.best

Test on Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 
Mac High Sierra

[image]

Edit: I am silly and was calling both Font Awesome 5 Pro and Font Awesome 5 Pro free using the CDN. I deleted the free version and it is working now. I would delete this question but don't want to be punished by Stack Overflow staff!

Comment: When I visit the site in my browser, I'm getting this error and many others from the same domain: "Refused to execute script from 'https://sdk.beeketing.com/js/beeketing.js?20180427' because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable. "

Comment: The plugin is buggy. But it is also working. So it's a tradeoff I guess.

Comment: If you're satisfied with any of the given answers, mark it as "best answer"

Answer (score 0):

That's because some icons changed from v4 to v5. For example, in that page you mention, the "sign in" icon, you can see in the source it's marked as `fa fa-sign-in` and in [Font Awesome Website](https://fontawesome.com/icons/sign-in-alt?style=solid) it says it has changed to `fas fa-sign-in-alt`, and it says:

> This icon replaces Font Awesome 4's fa-sign-in We created a shim to
>   help folks upgrade easily their existing projects from Font Awesome 4
>   to 5 and avoid those embarrassing missing icon moments.

Answer (score -1):

Font Awesome changes it icons from based on the version you are loading, I have experienced this myself where my icons suddenly become a `?` icon

Simply replace your icon as the current `<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>` and your problem should be fixed